# Exploit Format String Vulnerability / What was the attack? my guess is "printf(nameBuf); and that it should be "printf("%s", nameBuf);

Tags: linux

```
// Lab 2 -- String Format Attack: reading other items on the stack!
#include <stdio.h>
int win(){
  puts("Good job! Now run './vulnProg' and get the real secret number and string! ");
}
int main (int argc, char** argv){
  //Here is out secret number.
  //The user will never know what it is without the source code! /s
  int secret = 1337;
  char *nameBuf = malloc(20);
  // Make sure this string prints before we accept user input
  puts("Input name: ");
  // Get a string of characters from the user.
  read(0, nameBuf, 20);
  printf("Hello, ");
  printf(nameBuf);    <-------
  puts("\nDid you get the secret number? What is it? ");
  int num = 0;
  scanf("%d", &num);
  if(num-secret == 0){
    win();
  }
  printf("\nExiting...\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Exploit Format String Vulnerability / What was the attack? my guess is "printf(nameBuf); and that it should be "printf("%s", nameBuf);
Could you please explain how the attack works?

Comment: This can only work if the program is not compiled optimized in a way where `secret` isn't put on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

> my guess is "printf(nameBuf); and that it should be "printf("%s", nameBuf);

Your guess is correct.

> Could you please explain how the attack works?

Provided that the program is compiled e. g. with `-O0`, i. e. in a way where `secret` isn't optimized away from the stack, entering conversion specifications in place of the name results in `printf()` fetching *arguments* which weren't actually given; what is present on the stack is fetched and printed instead, among that potentially being the `secret` number.

Example *input*/output where `secret` is the sixth next item on the stack:

`Input name: 
%d %d %d %d %d %d
Hello, 149766152 20 -5603784 -144465003 -143142016 1337`